# I can't import Peewee in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

In Python 2 I can import peewee but when I run Python3 I can't import peewee. It says module not found.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: is peewee installed for python 3? Check with ``pip3 list``

Comment: I don't think I have pip3. I can run python3 but when try to pip3 it says command not found.

Comment: Ok I did it! I just installed pip3 and then installed peewee with pip3. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install pip3 and then run `pip3 install peewee` this show a progress bar of the installation
[image]